Is the exponential component of the Fourier transform $\exp(2 \pi i \omega u)$ or $\exp(-2 \pi i\omega u)$?
The question I was tasked with is:
"Suppose $\{X_t\}$ is a stationary process with spectral density function $f_X(\omega)$ and define
$$Y_t = \sum^\infty_{u=-\infty} c_uX_{t-u}$$
$$Z_t = Y_t +\sum^\infty_{u=-\infty}c_u(X_{t-u}-Y_{t-u})$$
Show that the spectral density function of $Z_t$ is
$$f_Z(w) =|1-(1- \psi(w))^2|^2 f_X(\omega),$$
where
$$\psi(\omega)=\sum^\infty_{u=-\infty}c_u \exp(2\pi i \omega u).$$
My textbook defines the exponential component of $\psi(\omega)$ to be $-2 \pi i \omega u$. I've read the positive one is Forward Fourier Transform, while the other is the Inverse, but the equation in my question seems to be forward Fourier Transform since I'm decomposing a signal into frequencies. Some other sources say that this is also simply a matter of convention that my instructor has picked. So which one is it?

There are several popular conventions. These ones all give the forward transform's exponent a $-$ sign, but I've seen conventions that reverse that.

This DSP SE question addresses why people tend to use the signs that way.
